# Link2SD error- "mount: Operation not supported on transparent endpoint"

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, system-error, partitions, link2sd

So I just rooted my Concord II, and installed Link2SD. I partitioned my SD card with MiniTool, and made a Fat32 and a ext2, both primary. But when after opening Link2SD and giving it root access, it gives me a popup saying select the file system of your SD card's second partition (see first screenshot below), and I select ext2 and press ok. But then a mount script error popup comes up saying mount script could not be created (see second screenshot). The error is "mount: Operation not supported on transparent endpoint". How can I fix this? These screenshots illustrate what's happening:

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

> Try with an ext4 partition.

From [www.link2sd.info/faq](http://www.link2sd.info/faq). I had the same issue and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Install [SDFix: KitKat Writable MicroSD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.sdfix) from the Google Play Store.

Then, using the latest [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD), format your flash in ext4.

Comment: Thanks, but will this work even if I'm on android 4.3(Jellybean)? SDFix seems to be to fix an issue introduced from Android 4.4 and up, so what effect would it have on my Concord?

Comment: @MikeyS Probably not. That Kitkat issue wasn't there before Kitkat, so a fix for it wouldn't find anything to fix. It either wouldn't run at all, or change nothing relevant.

Comment: @Izzy Yeah, thats what happens, after pressing run, I get an error saying "Update failed, platform.xml file could not be updated" :(   Is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: No idea. I have you tried to [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=link2sd+"mount%3A+Operation+not+supported+on+transparent+endpoint") and find many posts for exactly this device – but all of them must be yours. Is there any forum you missed? ;)

Comment: Lol, well I really want to get this fixed :p